# How to upload files received in a Lumen API to BOX API using guzzlehttp

Tags: php, lumen, guzzle, box

I am trying to upload files to the Box drive via its API. I upload this file from postman to an endpoint on my own personal Lumen API, then from this I intend to send the file to Box API. However, I keep getting the 500 server error response from Box API. This is the request from Postman.

[image]

Below is the controller function that gets the data from postman:

```
public function addFile(Request $request) {
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $fileName = $request->get("name");

    if ($file->getSize() > 1000000) {
        throw new BadRequestException(
            "Your file size is too big. Should be less that 1 mb."
        );
    }

    $boxApi = new BoxApi();
    $fileUploadResponse = $boxApi->uploadFile($file, $fileName);
    if ($fileUploadResponse->getStatusCode() == 201) {
        return $this->respond("File has been uploaded successfully", 201);
    }
}
```

And the BoxApi class method for uploading is this:

```
public function uploadFile(UploadedFile $file, $fileName)
{
    $endpoint = "/files/content";
    $response = $this->client->request(
        "POST",
        $this->boxApiUploadUrl . $endpoint,
        [
            "headers" => [
                "Authorization" => "Bearer AUTH_TOKEN",
                "Content-Type" => "multipart/form-data",
                "enctype" => "multipart/form-data"
            ],
            "multipart" => [
                [
                    "name" => "file",
                    "contents" => $file,
                    "filename" => $fileName
                ],
                [
                    "name" => "attributes",
                    "contents" => json_encode([
                        "name" => $fileName,
                        "parent" => ['id' => '30']
                    ])
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );

    return $response;
```

From all my research on stack overflow, I haven't found any code that passes the `headers` key and the `multipart` key at the same time. I am not sure if this could be the problem, but if I remove the `headers`, it raises an `UnAuthorizedException`.

I can't quite figure out what I am doing wrong or if it could be a problem with the API itself. Any help will be very appreciated.